# Redux route changes path but not rendering new page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Everything was working fine until I updated the route with some additional values and requirements (let call them: key and optional in the example below). When I click on the button to go to a new page, it changes the path URL (in the browser) but it stays on the same page (*MainPage*) with *no errors* and doesn't go to the *NewPage* or *TestSite*. I have included `withRouter` on the page. Any ideas how to fix this issue? Thanks!

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/:Key/:optional?' render={(props) => <MainPage key={props.match.params.key} optional={props.match.params.optional} />} />
        <Route exact path='/NewPage/:Key/:optional?' render={(props) => <NewPage />} />
        <Route exact path='/TestSite' render={(props) => <TestSite/>} />
    </Switch>   
</Router>
```

Render()

```
<Link to="/NewPage/Key"><button className="btn btn-warning">Open New Page</button></Link>
<Link to="/TestSite"><div className="btn btn-success">Open Test Page</div></Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, then I think the solution is to change the order of your `<Route />` components in your `<Switch />` like so:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>

        {/* Set this route as the first in the switch /*}
        <Route exact path='/NewPage/:Key/:optional?' render={(props) => <NewPage />} />

        <Route exact path='/TestSite' render={(props) => <TestSite/>} />

        {/* Set this route as last in the switch /*}
        <Route exact path='/:Key/:optional?' render={(props) => <MainPage key={props.match.params.key} optional={props.match.params.optional} />} />
    </Switch>   
</Router>
```

The reason for this, is that route precedence is based on the order that routes are defined in the switch.

So, when you navigate with `<Link to="/NewPage/Key">`, the `NewPage` part of the route will match `:Key`, and the `Key` part of the route will match `:optional?`. By reordering the routes as shown, this should case the expected `<NewPage />` component to show for `<Link to="/NewPage/Key">`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: probably gotta move it to the bottom of the `<Switch>` because `TestSite` will also be caught by `:Key`

Comment: Awesome! I got it now, thanks! I moved the MainPage route to the bottom and it worked

Comment: @DacreDenny @fila90 is right because the `MainPage` would think "TestSite" is the Key and because the next value is optional, it doesn't really matter if there is one or not